# Convert SQL query to a subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

odd request I know. But my client likes to change his mind more than I change my pants. The following is a snippet of my SQL query:

```
SELECT C.f_Name, C.l_Name, O.order_No, O.order_Date
FROM Customers AS C, Orders AS O,
WHERE C.customer_ID = O.order_No
```

I want to convert it into a sub query. Why? Because I have a **** tonne more to add to this query and I desperately need a kick start in the world of sub queries.
I attempted this:

```
SELECT C.f_Name, C.l_Name
FROM Customers AS C
WHERE C.customer_ID IN (SELECT O.order_No, O.order_Date FROM Orders AS O WHERE C.customer_ID = O.order_No)
```

But I'm obviously not grasping the concept cause it isn't working. Please help me stackers!

Sample data set (Very Small)

```
Customers Table

customer_ID | f_Name | l_Name
10            Akira    Dawson
11            Charlie  Frantooie

Orders Table

order_No | order_Date | 
10         2014-04-11 09:04:36
```

From this small snippet, Akira has made an order, but Charlie hasn't. I am using PHP to do CSV exports and I need to display all records regardless. So my expected result would be

```
Customer_ID | f_Name | l_Name | order_No | order_Date
10            Akira    Dawson     10       2014-04-11
11            Charlie  Frantooie  NA          NA
```

p.s `C.customer_ID = O.order_No` are what link a customer to an order

**TL;DR
Answer from @Turophile**

```
SELECT C.customer_ID, C.f_Name, C.l_Name, O.order_No, O.order_Date
FROM Customers AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders AS O
ON C.customer_ID = O.order_No
```

Comment: (1) What database are you using?  (MySQL or SQL Server); and (2) You can't do what you want.  The `select` clause has columns from both tables.

Comment: Hey, using MySQL. I'm also not understanding by "the select clause has columns from both tables" My fail attempt is just an example of how bad my sql skills are, lol

Comment: Give us a small set of sample starting data, and the results you expect.  Your initial attempt is throwing an error because you're returning multiple columns for an `IN` clause (allows multiple _rows_).  Most RDBMSs have optimizers that do things like pick good indices... and re-order joins/rewrite queries for better performance (within limits).  Simply rewriting to use a subquery may not change the actual path the system takes to retrieve your data; so _why_ the change to using a subquery?  What new issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: I can add a small set for you in my question shortly, I understand why i'm getting the error and am currently tinkering it. Why am I taking the long way instead of joining the customer and order table with a simple WHERE customer_ID = order_No? Well, I have a lot more matches to make in different tables. like the customers tour ID with the ID in the Tour table and so on. My current code WHERE C.customer_ID = O.order_No AND C.trip_Taken = T.tour_ID won't suffice anymore because it doesn't match the clients needs

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Snippet added into my question.

Comment: Are your order no's and customer id's really equivalent items? That seems odd, but you do have: WHERE C.customer_ID = O.order_No - This means that a given customer number can only have one order...

Comment: Yes, this is the clients needs. Don't have budget to future proof it a.k.a one customer to multiple orders.

Comment: You want `LEFT JOIN`.  There's future proofing, and then there's good basic design.  At minimum you need to call the join column the same logical thing (`customerId`, obviously).  Preferrably you'd have an autogen id for orders as well.  I'm surprised the client is paying for a store; there are existing applications in php already, some likely free.  That, or just sell on an established ecom platform like Amazon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let me tear apart your example so that hopefully I can increase your knowledge and understanding.

```
SELECT C.f_Name, C.l_Name
FROM Customers AS C
WHERE C.customer_ID IN (
  SELECT O.order_No, O.order_Date 
  FROM Orders AS O 
  WHERE C.customer_ID = O.order_No
  )
```

This is a start, but you must understand that a sub-select like this in the `WHERE` clause does not provide values to the result - it only qualifies which rows from the main select are included.

Notice that your `WHERE` clause has `C.customer_ID IN` which means that the sub-select must return a set of customer_ID values. Now, these can be called something else, but need to be `customer_ID`s. 
In your example, you are returning `O.order_No, O.order_Date` , which is wrong in two ways - first, neither seems like it would contain a `customer_ID`, and second, you are returning two things, which is a no go - you can't match a single customer number against a list which has two columns - think about doing this in program code - you can't say  `int == (Object){int,int}`.

If you want these values in the resultset, they need to be selected in the main (outer) query, so they need to get there somehow, which means that a subquery probably isn't the answer - a subquery as part of the `WHERE` clause is for refining the resultset, for excluding some unwanted data.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT C.f_Name, C.l_Name, order_No, O.order_Date
FROM Customers AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders AS O
ON C.customer_ID = O.customer_ID
```

but if you MUST use a subselect, and assuming you don't need to return the order details:

```
SELECT C.f_Name, C.l_Name
FROM Customers AS C
WHERE C.customer_ID IN (SELECT O.customer_ID  FROM Orders)
```

Note also that typically one customer could have many orders, so you have to allow for that.
I hope that helps. Ask questions if you need to.

---

**EDIT** Based upon the example added to the question, I think the correct query would be:

```
SELECT C.customer_ID, C.f_Name, C.l_Name, O.order_No, O.order_Date
FROM Customers AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders AS O
ON C.customer_ID = O.order_No
```

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca441/1

Note that it is BAD to have customer numbers in a column named Order_No - Why isn't it Customer_ID ??? To explain, at the moment, there is no "order number", the `order_No` column contains `customer_ID` values. What happens when a client places multiple orders? Here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/297e1/1  and as you can see, the "order number" is the same for all orders from each client. Your orders table needs another column, `customer_ID` added, and `order_No` can then be a unique key for each order. It also then makes it obvious that the two tables should be joined on `customer_ID`.

Comment: thanks for the breakdown, After some further reading I am slowly understanding subqueries. Mind you I tried your example out but had no such luck. I have modified my question with a sample dataset and my expected result if that helps you at all. Unfortunately I do need to return order details. I do appreciate the break down, again, thank you!

Comment: Why isn't it Customer_ID ??? I'm just working on existing code. Some uni grad thought they were top knotch. Now it's up to me to fix it and get sh!t working correctly. There are other bad names in the database which will make you cringe too. But for your safety, I won't show you. However your code helped me get over the hurdle and solve my problem! Thank you for you help, truly appreciated!